# java.lang.StackOverflowError with Android Spring and SSL

Tags: java, android, spring, ssl

Our application consumes a WebApi that is secured with a SSL certificate. Mostly times everything works fine but, sometimes, the application crashes with the following error:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:118)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.DefiniteLengthInputStream.read(DefiniteLengthInputStream.java:74)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:118)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.DefiniteLengthInputStream.read(DefiniteLengthInputStream.java:74)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:118)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.DefiniteLengthInputStream.read(DefiniteLengthInputStream.java:74)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:118)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.DefiniteLengthInputStream.read(DefiniteLengthInputStream.java:74)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.util.io.Streams.readFully(Streams.java:49)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.util.io.Streams.readFully(Streams.java:40)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.getBuffer(ASN1InputStream.java:384)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.createPrimitiveDERObject(ASN1InputStream.java:447)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildObject(ASN1InputStream.java:184)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readObject(ASN1InputStream.java:272)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildEncodableVector(ASN1InputStream.java:193)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildDEREncodableVector(ASN1InputStream.java:204)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildObject(ASN1InputStream.java:173)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readObject(ASN1InputStream.java:272)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildEncodableVector(ASN1InputStream.java:193)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildDEREncodableVector(ASN1InputStream.java:204)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildObject(ASN1InputStream.java:173)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readObject(ASN1InputStream.java:272)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildEncodableVector(ASN1InputStream.java:193)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildDEREncodableVector(ASN1InputStream.java:204)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildObject(ASN1InputStream.java:173)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readObject(ASN1InputStream.java:272)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildEncodableVector(ASN1InputStream.java:193)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildDEREncodableVector(ASN1InputStream.java:204)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildObject(ASN1InputStream.java:173)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readObject(ASN1InputStream.java:272)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.CertPathValidatorUtilities.getObject(CertPathValidatorUtilities.java:339)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.CertPathValidatorUtilities.getExtensionValue(CertPathValidatorUtilities.java:325)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.RFC3280CertPathUtilities.processCertD(RFC3280CertPathUtilities.java:1268)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.java:310)
at com.sec.android.security.pkix.SecCertPathValidatorSpi.engineValidate(SecCertPathValidatorSpi.java:100)
at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:190)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:295)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:202)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:612)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:406)
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:146)
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:107)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:161)
at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse executeInternal(org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders,byte[])(SourceFile:76)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse executeInternal(org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders)(SourceFile:48)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse execute()(SourceFile:84)
at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$RequestExecution.org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse execute(org.springframework.http.HttpRequest,byte[])(SourceFile:91)
at com.myapplication.webapi.spring.interceptors.IonAuthenticationClientInterceptor.org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse intercept(org.springframework.http.HttpRequest,byte[],org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestExecution)(SourceFile:82)
at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$RequestExecution.org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse execute(org.springframework.http.HttpRequest,byte[])(SourceFile:81)
at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse executeInternal(org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders,byte[])(SourceFile:67)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse executeInternal(org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders)(SourceFile:48)

//The stack below repeats about 100 times
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse execute()(SourceFile:84)
at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$RequestExecution.org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse execute(org.springframework.http.HttpRequest,byte[])(SourceFile:91)
at com.myapplication.webapi.spring.interceptors.IonAuthenticationClientInterceptor.org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse intercept(org.springframework.http.HttpRequest,byte[],org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestExecution)(SourceFile:82)
at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$RequestExecution.org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse execute(org.springframework.http.HttpRequest,byte[])(SourceFile:81)
at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse executeInternal(org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders,byte[])(SourceFile:67)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse executeInternal(org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders)(SourceFile:48)
//End of stack that repeats 100 times

at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$RequestExecution.org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse execute(org.springframework.http.HttpRequest,byte[])(SourceFile:91)
at com.myapplication.webapi.spring.interceptors.IonAuthenticationClientInterceptor.org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse intercept(org.springframework.http.HttpRequest,byte[],org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestExecution)(SourceFile:82)
at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$RequestExecution.org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse execute(org.springframework.http.HttpRequest,byte[])(SourceFile:81)
at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse executeInternal(org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders,byte[])(SourceFile:67)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse executeInternal(org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders)(SourceFile:48)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse execute()(SourceFile:84)
at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$RequestExecution.org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse execute(org.springframework.http.HttpRequest,byte[])(SourceFile:91)
at com.myapplication.webapi.spring.interceptors.IonAuthenticationClientInterceptor.org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse intercept(org.springframework.http.HttpRequest,byte[],org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestExecution)(SourceFile:82)
at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$RequestExecution.org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse execute(org.springframework.http.HttpRequest,byte[])(SourceFile:81)
at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse executeInternal(org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders,byte[])(SourceFile:67)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse executeInternal(org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders)(SourceFile:48)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse execute()(SourceFile:84)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.java.lang.Object doExecute(java.net.URI,org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,org.springframework.web.client.RequestCallback,org.springframework.web.client.ResponseExtractor)(SourceFile:536)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.java.lang.Object execute(java.lang.String,org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,org.springframework.web.client.RequestCallback,org.springframework.web.client.ResponseExtractor,java.util.Map)(SourceFile:506)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity exchange(java.lang.String,org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,org.springframework.http.HttpEntity,java.lang.Class,java.util.Map)(SourceFile:455)
at com.myapplication.webapi.smartclients.SynchronizationClient_.org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity requestUpdateFile(long,long)(SourceFile:95)
at com.myapplication.services.synchronization.SynchronizationTask$2$1.org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity call()(SourceFile:514)
at com.myapplication.services.synchronization.SynchronizationTask$2$1.java.lang.Object call()(SourceFile:509)
at com.myapplication.managers.rest.RestManager$RestRequest.java.lang.Object execute()(SourceFile:110)
at com.myapplication.managers.rest.RestManager.java.lang.Object executeRequest(java.lang.String,int,com.myapplication.webapi.spring.RestErrorProcessor,java.util.concurrent.Callable)(SourceFile:67)
at com.myapplication.services.synchronization.SynchronizationTask$2.void run()(SourceFile:506)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

There isn´t a specific WebApi call that causes this problem... It has been reported on almost all WebApi methods available on our system, but, as I said before, on the same device, it works very well most of the time.

I also noticed that this started do happen after enabling SSL on our webservice server.

Does anybody knows what is happening and also, how could I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try increasing the stack size for the thread doing the REST call.
The stack size for main UI thread in Android is limited but theoretically you can start a new thread with an arbitrary size (in this case 1MB), as follows

```
ThreadGroup group = new ThreadGroup("restAPIgroup");
new Thread(group, runnableObject, "YourThreadName", 1024*1024).start();
```

Comment: Hello Katerina! Thanks a lot! I will try your approach but I really worried about the same piece of code being called over and over as the stacktrace shows... I think that, increasing the stack size will only make the system repeats these call before failing again...

Comment: The reason might be that you have a very complicated SSL certificate, in which case having a stack of appropriate size would solve your issues.

Comment: How could I know if my certificate is a complicated one? It have a 2048 key length and two intermediate certificates between it and the root certificate. Thanks a lot!